# extract data from JSON feed

Tags: android, json

Can anyone tell me how to get the `title` and `href` attributes  from  the following JSON?

```
{
 "funding": [ {
                "FIELD1": "1",
                "FIELD2": "01/12/2016",
                "FIELD3": "<a title=\"SidQam\" href=\"http://www.sidqam.com/\">SidQam</a>",
                "FIELD4": "Technology",
                "FIELD5": "Healthcare Software System",
                "FIELD6": "Noida",
                "FIELD7": "SQue Capital, Grace Capital Ventures, Soham Vencaps",
                "FIELD8": "Private Equity",
                "FIELD9": "1,200,000"
              }
            ]
}
```

Comment: u have to parse the `FIELD3` attribute ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("funding");
String link = jsonArray.getString("FIELD3");
String href = link.substring(link.indexOf("http://"), link.indexOf("\">"));
//href must be clear link
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it dint help,rather my app got crashed once i wrote this.although it worked fine till parsing "FIELD3" value

Comment: what's the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @Coder its java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException what i experienced. can you correct it??

Comment: It is mostly around the sub string formation. Takes those index values into temp variables and see if they are going out of range.

Comment: yea now its working..i did typo in that substring formation. i wrote "https" instead of "http" .i guess, Also i need to get that http address written in valid format in that JSON feed. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: and thank  you @First Code,your code is absolutely correct.

Comment: if it is solved your problem, please accept my answer @Møhìt Müñjâl

Comment: @First Code how?!!

Comment: there is tick button left of answer